# Highlight sections of the canvas in jqPlot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot for some charting. I would like to highlight regions of the background of the chart. I would like to specify rectangles bounded by the values on an axis that are the entire length of the opposite axis.

Is this do-able out of the box, or must I alter the code? Would this be a good usage for a plugin? Is there documentation on how to write one?

**Update**: Looks like the `fill` option on the series might be helpful.

**Update 2**: Or maybe the `GridCanvasRenderer` or the `ShapeRenderer`.

Answer (score -1):

I implemented it myself with about 20 lines of code in `CanvasGridRenderer`. Works pretty well.